# How can I disable default request headers from apache httpclient 4?

Tags: java, apache-httpclient-4.x, apache-commons-httpclient

I am using apache common httpclient 4.3.3 to make http 1.0 request. Here is how I make the request

```
HttpClient client = HttpClientBuilder.create().build();
HttpPost post = new HttpPost(url);
post.setProtocolVersion(new ProtocolVersion("HTTP", 1, 0));

 // trying to remove default headers but it doesn't work
post.removeHeaders("User-Agent");
post.removeHeaders("Accept-Encoding");
post.removeHeaders("Connection");

post.setEntity(new ByteArrayEntity(ba) );

HttpResponse response = client.execute(post);
```

However, i can see that there are other headers automatically added to my request to the server like

```
Connection: Keep-Alive
User-Agent: Apache-HttpClient/4.3.3 (java 1.5)
Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate
```

How can I tell httpclient not to include any other headers? I tried to removed those headers with post.removeHeaders(xxxx) but it doesn't work. Can you show me how?

Thanks,

Answer (score 14):

If you call `HttpClientBuilder.create()`, you will have a httpClientBuilder.
And httpClientBuilder has a lot config for default headers and this will be used to make intercepters( ex: RequestAcceptEncoding ).

For example, RequestAcceptEncoding, which implements  HttpRequestInterceptor, makes `Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate` header when HttpProcessor.process() is invoked.
And httpProcessor.process() will be invoked just before invoking
`final CloseableHttpResponse response = this.requestExecutor.execute(route, request, context, execAware);`

You can see this code at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.ProtocolExec of httpclient-4.3.6 line 193.

If you want to remove `Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate`, call `HttpClientBuilder.disableContentCompression()` like below.

```
HttpClient client = HttpClientBuilder.create().disableContentCompression().build();
```

In short, HttpClientBuilder has a lot of flags to disable/enable HttpRequestInterceptor. If you disable/enable those HttpRequestInterceptor, you can exclude/include default headers.

Sorry for my poor English, and hope you get what I mean.

Answer (score 7):

```
CloseableHttpClient hc = HttpClients.custom()
        .setHttpProcessor(HttpProcessorBuilder.create().build())
        .build();
```

The code snippet above demonstrates how to create an HttpClient instance with an empty (no-op) protocol processor, which guarantees no request headers will ever be added to outgoing messages executed by such client

Comment: I am not sure what kind of additional explanations are to be expected here. The code snippet above demonstrates how to create an HttpClient instance with an empty (no-op) protocol processor, which guarantees no request headers will ever be added to outgoing messages executed by such client

Comment: this method remove all headers! you must config this

Answer (score 5):

You want to do your 'cleanup' at the end, after HttpClient is done modifying the request. You can do this by calling addInterceptorLast on HttpClientBuilder as below.

```
HttpClient client = HttpClientBuilder.create().addInterceptorLast( 
                        new HttpRequestInterceptor() {
                            public void process(HttpRequest request, HttpContext context){
                                request.removeHeaders("Host");
                                request.removeHeaders("Connection");
                            }
                        }   
                ).build();
```

I create an anonymous class implementing HttpRequestInterceptor. Take whatever header modifications you need done before the request is sent, and put them in the process method.

Comment: Does this ensure that once the request is sent to the destination it would not have the Host and Connection headers? As far as I know HttpClient by default would add these headers irrespective of us manually removing them or not.

Also, when is the process() method called? I tried debugging this but I see no call being made.

Answer (score 0):

I think you could add your implementation of `HttpRequestInterceptor` with `client.addRequestInterceptor()` 

 
**or** (better) 
remove all interceptors that add headers to the request (`RequestUserAgent`, `RequestDefaultHeaders`, `RequestClientConnControl`, `RequestAcceptEncoding`, ...).

Removing them is also easy:

```
client.removeRequestInterceptorByClass(RequestAcceptEncoding.class);
```

Comment: i don't see the method removeRequestInterceptorByClass(xxxx) for HttpClient. Where can I set that method?

Comment: https://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-4.3.x/httpclient/apidocs/org/apache/http/impl/client/AbstractHttpClient.html#removeRequestInterceptorByClass(java.lang.Class) But I saw the whole API is deprecated for 4.3