# customizing HTTP Request Headers

Tags: http, request, http-headers

How we can control over the number of header going with the HTTP request? e.g.; If I don't want to send the "Cache-Control" header,how to control it?
I am using HttpClient for sending a JSON formatted request.
Using 4.5.1 version of org.apache.httpcomponents  and 3.1 version of commons-httpclient in maven dependencies.

Comment: In what environment? Looks like you're using HttpClient, but add this info to the question.

Comment: @fvu Yes , using Apache commons' HttpClient , sending json formatted request.

Comment: Well, then add that information to the question and please include the version of httpclient used.

Comment: I think this is a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23291209/how-can-i-disable-default-request-headers-from-apache-httpclient-4 then, can you please check?

Comment: @fvu , yes the link was stating the same question i did asked,

seeing that link got how to remove one header "Accept-Encoding" by doing change in my code as :
CloseableHttpClient httpClient = HttpClientBuilder.create().disableContentCompression().build();

 but not able to remove these headers :
Content-Length: 417
Connection: Keep-Alive
User-Agent: Apache-HttpClient/4.5.1 (Java/1.7.0_79)

Comment: There also it's relevant to add that information to the question: what you want, to optimize your chances of getting a good answer, is that someone who reads your question gets a complete and coherent overview of your problem, and of the things you already tried, and how and why they did not work out as you wanted.

Comment: @fvu,ok sir, actually i'm new to stackoverflow , thanks for making me correct.
Please tell any way how to remove these default headers from request?