# RestAssured: How to avoid sending the User-Agent header in a request

Tags: java, user-agent, rest-assured

For one of my test, I want to send a request without User-Agent header. Even if I don't specify it in the request, a default one with value `Apache-HttpClient/4.5.9 (Java/1.8.0_222)` is added to the request.

Is there a way to disable this behavior?

This is the request I am trying to send. As can be seen, the User-Agent is not set explicitly but it is still added implicitly by Apache HttpClient.

```
RequestSpecification request = given().
                header(HttpHeaders.ACCEPT, "application/json").
                header(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_TYPE, "application/json");        
if (includeAuthorizationHeader) {
   request = request.header(HttpHeaders.AUTHORIZATION, bearerAuth(token));
}
Response response = request.
         body(DataRequest.builder().
         id("test-client").
         timestamp(DATE_FORMAT.format(Date.from(Instant.now()))).
         build()).
         expect().
         statusCode(expectedStatusCode).
         contentType(expectedContentType).
         when().
         post(endpoint + "/api/test");
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please read [mcve] and edit your post accordingly

Comment: Added the code having the issue.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I disable default request headers from apache httpclient 4?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23291209/how-can-i-disable-default-request-headers-from-apache-httpclient-4) - seems that this Q/A offers a few alternatives.  I expect that one of them would work for you.

Comment: I am not aware if we can create a custom HttpClient while using RestAssured. If that can be done, then I can try to use the technique mentioned in that answer.

Comment: ...otherwise, I concur that you need to supply a [MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), or at least a piece of code with all of the variables that are non-obvious in terms of type and origin defined so that one can hope to get something similar to at least compile.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution to set a custom User Agent with RestAssured httpClientConfig.

```
HttpClientConfig httpClientConfig = RestAssured.config.getHttpClientConfig();
RestAssured.config.httpClient(httpClientConfig.httpClientFactory(() -> {
    RestAssuredConfig config = RestAssured.config();
    HttpClientConfig httpClientConfig = config.getHttpClientConfig();
    RestAssured.config = config.httpClient(
        httpClientConfig.httpClientFactory(() -> {
            DefaultHttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpProtocolParams.setUserAgent(client.getParams(), "User Agent A");
            return client;
        }
    );
}
```